# MVVM Cross null references when unit testing MxvAsyncCommand

Tags: mvvmcross

We have recently upgraded to MvvMCross 6.2.2 and noticed we had to change to use Mvx.IoCProvider.

We have found that if we are constructing an MvxAsyncCommand in a ViewModel this causes a null reference exception on all unit tests that call this constructor

*

```
Result StackTrace:  
at MvvmCross.Commands.MvxCommandBase..ctor()
   at MvvmCross.Commands.MvxAsyncCommand..ctor(Func`1 execute, Func`1 canExecute, Boolean allowConcurrentExecutions)
   at App.Mobile.Core.ViewModels.TestViewModel..ctor(IMvxNavigationService navigation, ITestService encService, ILogger logger)
   at App.Mobile.Core.UnitTests.TestViewModelTests.<TestViewModel_Prepare>d__1.MoveNext()
```

*

Looking at the source in github the problem is due to Mvx.IocProvider being null.

```
public MvxCommandBase()
    {
        if (!Mvx.IoCProvider.TryResolve<IMvxCommandHelper>(out _commandHelper))
            _commandHelper = new MvxWeakCommandHelper();

        var alwaysOnUIThread = MvxSingletonCache.Instance == null || MvxSingletonCache.Instance.Settings.AlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread;
        ShouldAlwaysRaiseCECOnUserInterfaceThread = alwaysOnUIThread;
    }
```

A fix has been implemented in the "develop" branch but this isn't available on nuget.

```
public MvxCommandBase()
    {
        // fallback on MvxWeakCommandHelper if no IoC has been set up
        if (!Mvx.IoCProvider?.TryResolve(out _commandHelper) ?? true)
            _commandHelper = new MvxWeakCommandHelper();

        // default to true if no Singleton Cache has been set up
        var alwaysOnUIThread = MvxSingletonCache.Instance?.Settings.AlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread ?? true;
        ShouldAlwaysRaiseCECOnUserInterfaceThread = alwaysOnUIThread;
    }
```

Does anyone know of a workaround to initialize this IoCProvider within our unit test projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/6.2.2/MvvmCross/Mvx.cs#L17) the `IoCProvider` is resolved by getting the singleton of `IMvxIoCProvider`

```
public static IMvxIoCProvider IoCProvider => MvxSingleton<IMvxIoCProvider>.Instance;
```

So all you have to do is to initialize the `IMvxIoCProvider`. 
As an example you can use [this test](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/6.2.2/UnitTests/MvvmCross.UnitTest/Base/MvxIoCPropertyInjectionTest.cs#L54), so in order to initialize it, you have to do:

```
MvxSingleton.ClearAllSingletons(); // This should be done in the test to clear all references of previous tests if necessary.
var instance = MvxIoCProvider.Initialize();
```

HIH

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect.  I've added the Initialize() call to the Class Initialisation for the tests, bit of a pain but at least not getting a shed load of failed unit tests!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept/vote the answer please